# Android DrawerLayout not responding to button click event

Tags: android, button, navigation-drawer

I have a `DrawerLayout` component in my activity, but I'm not using `ActionBar`.

This is my `main_activity.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </FrameLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="650dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/categories_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:background="@drawable/button_category"/>
```

In my `MainActivity` I try to open/close the `DrawerLayout` by clicking on my `Button`.

Here is my `Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     private ImageButton categoriesButton;
     private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
     private ListView drawerMenu;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     categoriesButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.categories_button);
     categoriesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

          if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerMenu)) {
               drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerMenu);
          }else {
               drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerMenu);
          }

       }
     });

     drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
     drawerMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
     MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(context, getCategories());
     drawerMenu.setAdapter(myAdapter);

     }    
}
```

When I click the `Button` the first time it does not respond, but after I open the `DrawerLayout` manually it works perfect.

Does anybody know what is wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Just move your button OnClick code below drawerMenu.setAdapter(myAdapter);

Comment: no, still not working :(

Comment: replace   drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerMenu)  with drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START) and you are done.

Comment: no...it's really weird, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! In the xml, the `Listview` visibility needs to be set to `visible`. It was set to `gone` (I took this code from the oficial documentation).

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="650dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Anyway now it works. Thanks for your help!